# Searching a vector for an object with a specific variable using indexOf() in Java

Tags: java, vector, indexof

I'm trying to find an object held in a vector that has a specific integer for one of the object's variables using indexOf(). I picture it in my head like this: vector.indexOf(Object.variable=x) but that isn't working and I'm not sure if you can even use indexOf like that. If this is possible could someone please provide me with the proper formatting, if not could someone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think `indexOf()` will not suffice for your need. You should really traverse into your list.

`for ( "Object Type" x : "Vector" ) {

```
if( x.getIntegerValue() == "some integer" ){
    // do something here
    break;
}
```

}`

Answer (score 0):

If you use Guava, there is [Iterables.indexOf](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#indexOf%28java.lang.Iterable,%20com.google.common.base.Predicate%29):

For example, If you have `Vector<Employee> employees`, to find the index by employee id:

```
final int index = Iterables.indexOf(employees, new Predicate<Employee>() {
  public boolean apply(final Employee employee) {
    return employee.getId() == 10;
  }
});
```